# How to create mail composer screen in android?

Tags: android, email

Currently i am working in Android application, To create mail composer screen so i tried to create a mail composer screen my level best, but i didn't know, how to make this screen? please any one guide me.

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

```
 Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "yourid@gmail.com"});
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Contact Us");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text field here);
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to show the mail composer screen (Above i mentioned for your reference).

Comment: I think the question is about getting the values in the fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code for the `compose mail` android `automatically` display this kind of the screen on your devices.

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "yourid@gmail.com"});
         email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Contact Us");
         email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text field here);

                email.setType("message/rfc822");

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Try ! Good Luck.

Comment: sorry to say this, I tried this but the result comes "No applications can perform this action" Title of the alert is Choose an email client

Comment: I think to add any thing in Manifest file

Comment: How to fix this issue? help me

Comment: Sounds like you haven't any email app in your device.

Comment: Yes, i didn't have email application in my emulator, then how to installed this?

Comment: @Minu If any problem then inform me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply rahul, now i check it and let you know

Comment: Thank you so much Rahul, i got this successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to create a LinearLayout vertical, and insert three EditText with hint. For the third field (Compose mail), you can change the weight of the widget to fill the parent.

Don't forget to put the height of your layout to "FILL_PARENT"

Hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change type to `"text/plain"` instead of `"message/rfc822"` following the code snippet:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);                emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "yourid@gmail.com"});
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

if u check this in emulator use android version 2.2 and above it works for me